# Get styleData.depth from other column than 0

Tags: treeview, qml

I have a QtQuick1 TreeView and would like to access the depth of the current row in a delegate.

`styleData.depth` provides exactly what I need. However, only for column 0. I need this piece of information for columns >0. There, `styleData.depth` is reliably 0 on every level.

What is the most elegant way to access the depth in the other columns? Putting the depth into my model is a very *unelegant* possibility that I would like to circumvent.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, misleaded by the name. Indeed it should have that information: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-treeviewstyle.html.
Please provide a minimal example to help in solving your question.

Comment: @Amfasis I have described my issue completely. The first column does have this piece of information, the second and all following columns only have zero. No example code adds information

Comment: But a code example might help me... Maybe it's possible to somehow have the first column hidden in the other columns? Although I do remember seeing Qt Widget Treeviews which only have the first column indented, so that might explain why they did not provide the information for other columns